# Fluent TestValidate not raising validation errors for rules set on List with SetValidator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mstest, fluentvalidation

While using Fluent's Test Helpers TestValidate method to unit test my rules, it throws TestValidationException when List of object is null. The validator setup specifies the **NotNull** rule.

Validator looks like below

```
public class RequestValidator : AbstractValidator<Request>
{
    public RulebookRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleForEach(x => x.EntryRequests).SetValidator(new EntryRequestValidator()).NotNull(); // Would like to validate this rule when EntryRequests is null.
    }
}
```

Child validator looks like this,

```
public class EntryRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<EntryRequest>
{
        public EntryRequestValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.EntryRequestId).NotEmpty();
            RuleForEach(x => x.Messages).NotNull().SetValidator(new MessagesValidator());
        }
 }
```

And in my unit test

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_Have_Error_When_Object_Is_Empty()
{
    // arrange
    Request model = new () { EntryRequests = new () };
    var validator = new RequestValidator();

    // assert
    var result = validator.TestValidate(model);

    // act
    Assert.IsFalse(result.IsValid);
    result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Id)
            .WithErrorCode(NotEmptyValidatorErrorCode);
    result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Name)
            .WithErrorCode(NotEmptyValidatorErrorCode);
    result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.EntryRequests); // throws ValidateTestException. 
 }
```

Is this the right approach to test child validators on a List in Unit test? Looking for a way to use TestValidate to unit test this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validator works correctly, but has one tiny problem.

Let's look at this rule:

`RuleForEach(x => x.EntryRequests).SetValidator(new EntryRequestValidator()).NotNull();`

It basically says: Run a NotNull check (and execute EntryRequestValidator)  against every element in the `EntryRequest` collection.

It does not work because your collection is **empty**: `EntryRequests = new ()`. It has no elements, so there is nothing to validate.

Change it to:

```
RuleFor(x => x.EntryRequests).NotEmpty(); // throws validation error when collection is null or empty
RuleForEach(x => x.EntryRequests).SetValidator(new EntryRequestValidator()).NotNull();
```

With above rules you would get validation error when:

- EntryRequests = null
- EntryRequests = empty list
- any element of this list is null

plus all validations from nested validator

Comment: thanks for explaining the details and pointing out the error in my solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RulebookRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<Request>
{
    public RulebookRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.EntryRequests).NotNull()
            .ForEach(element => element.SetValidator(new EntryRequestValidator()).NotNull());
    }
}
```

you need to check for null for object, then set the validator for collection elements.

For readiblity you can define a custom rule builder extension method.

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, IEnumerable<TK>> MustBeValidCollection<T, TK>(
        this IRuleBuilder<T, IEnumerable<TK>> ruleBuilder,
        AbstractValidator<TK> validator)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.NotNull()
            .ForEach(collection => collection.NotNull().SetValidator(validator));
    }
```

and use it like  `RuleFor(x => x.EntryRequests).MustBeValidCollection(new EntryRequestValidator());`

Comment: thank you for the recommendation, I like the extension you recommended :) +1 for that approach. Actually, both the solutions worked for me :)